# Are customs stops required for private flights within the Schengen Area?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, international, eu

I would like to make a VFR flight from Switzerland to Germany and Germany to France and then France to Switzerland.

For the first step: Switzerland to Germany I know that I have to fill a custom form AND a flight plan while taking off and landing on an airport with custom services. The same for France to Germany.

HOWEVER from Germany to France is this rule applicable (note that the plane is registered in Switzerland)? I cannot find an official website?

Answer (score 1):

The European Union has also something called EEA - European Economic Area. Within the EEA it is not required to fill out anything except a flight plan between Germany and France. 
Switzerland, as stated, is not part of the European Economic Area and therefor customs are required.

Just in addition, Schengen is for passport free travel and not for taxes.

Comment: Schengen may be passport-free but you still need to be able to prove your country of residence, a passport or a "National Identity Card" are valid forms of residency, so you do need to take some documents with you.

Comment: so custom is required between France and Germany if the plane if registered in Switzerland?, apologies but the answer is not clear to me

Comment: It’s not about where the plane is registered, it’s about from where you come. No customs within the EU.

Comment: @branchwarren you'd pass customs when bringing the plane into the EU from Switzerland, not when subsequently flying it between EU nations. It gets more complicated in this specific case as Switzerland is not part of the EU but is part of the Schengen common customs region...